# Sum array diagonally with Inverted location

Tags: arrays, vb.net

How to sum an array the array maybe will be `10x10` or `2x2` or `3x3`

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

i want to sum the Inverted digonal start from `[1,3]` end `[3,1]` but we want to consider that the length of the array could change.

Comment: What is the code used to populate your array?

Comment: Did you try something at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it (Assuming your Array is called `x`):

```
    Dim Sum As Double = 0

    For i = 0 To UBound(x, 2)
        Sum += x(UBound(x, 2) - i, i)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array will always be square (i.e. 2x2, 6x6, 200x200, etc) then the following pseudo-code will produce the result you are after:

```
x = [square array]
i = 0
j = x.length - 1
sum = 0

while (i < x.length)
    sum += x[j--][i++]
```